# double variable with space every 000 but without omitting the decimal part

Tags: java

I need to set a big number with a decimal part into a TextView. But I need
 that number to be formatted with a space at every 000 and with the decimal symbol.(ex. 10 000 000.23)
I'm doing that about the space

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
tvpuntis.setText(formatter.format(xyz));
```

but like that i cant see decimal, xyz is a double and have by default decimal..

Comment: please stop explaining what you are trying to achieve, show it. What is the input, what is the output and *then* explain *why* that output should be received / according to what logic.

Comment: “but like that i cant see decimal”  —What *do* you see?

Comment: @luk2302 its simply that, i have a script that increase the value of xyz and a button that put this number into textview

Comment: @VGR with this code the output is 100 000 000 and the part after the comma is hidden

Comment: And what is the line of code that assigns a value to `xyz`?

Comment: the code that assign value is a button,         btclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                xyz=xyz +1500;
            }
        });

Comment: Decimal is a *radix.* Do you mean the decimal *point?* The *fractional* part? Please express yourself clearly.

Comment: `formatter = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE); formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(3); // other settings as needed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a decimal format pattern and a grouping separator symbol as follows.

```
String pattern = "###,###.###";
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
tvpuntis.setText(formatter.format(xyz));
```